# What does the Gems Upgrade notice in the Character menu mean?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

In the Characters menu, there's an orange "UPGRADE" notice next to my Gems display. I checked at a rest site and saw I didn't have enough materials to upgrade my gems, so what is this notice for?

[image: gems upgrade notice]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the "UPGRADE" message appears as such, this means you have recently<sup>1</sup> upgraded an existing gem, or crafted a new one. By navigating to the gem selection screen in the character menu, a gem will have an orange dot on the top-right of it indicating it has been upgraded/created. If you hover over all the gems with this dot, the "UPGRADE" message will go away.

---

<sup>1</sup> Recently is relative, since this will stay as long as you have unchecked upgrades.